# Benefits when using static init in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, webrtc

Recently I've discovered [webrtc-ios example from Github](https://github.com/gandg/webrtc-ios). While I was browsing though the project I noticed that VideoView class uses static method and I'm not sure is that necessary or not.
VideoView is subclass of UIView and it overrides two init methods, `initWithFrame:` and `initWithCoder:`. I know it's normal to override those init methods and then use some method for setting up other stuff, like `- (void)setup;`.

But VideoView class uses static function, `static void init(VideoView *self)`. Question is are there benefits when using static function vs. normal ObjC method?

Code in VideoView class looks like this:

```
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

     if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
         init(self);
     }
     return self; 
}

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {

     if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
         init(self);
     }
     return self; 
}

 static void init(VideoView *self) { ... }
```

Comment: I think this would be considered bad practice. It looks like someone trying to shoehorn a C++ construct (I'm guessing) into objective-c.

Comment: I was confused first time I saw that approach because I don't see any requirements for using static functions here. Still I think developer had his reasons why he did it in this way.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One difference between using a static function  and an Objective-C method is that
the static function cannot be overriden in a subclass. If the common init code is done
in a

```
- (void)setup;
```

method, and a subclass `MyVideoView` of `VideoView` happens to implement a method with the same name, then

```
[[MyVideoView alloc] initWithFrame:..]
```

will call the subclass implementation, which might not be wanted.

In your code,
`initWithFrame`/`initWithCoder` will always call the local `init()` function, even if
an instance of a subclass is initialized.

*If* the common initialization is done in a *method*, then the method name should be more
specific, to avoid that it is overriden "accidentally", for example

```
-(void)commonVideoViewSetup;
```