# Incorrect scope

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have two classes

**A.h**

```
@interface A : UIView

@end
```

**A.m**

```
@implementation A

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)aDecoder{
  self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
   if(self){ 
      [self initialize];
   }
return self;
}

-(void)initialize{
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self name:keyboardnotificationwillshow];
}
@end
```

**B.h**

```
@interface B : A

@end

@implementation B

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)aDecoder{
  self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
   if(self){ 
      [self initialize];
   }
return self;
}

-(void)initialize{
 //do some stuff to prepare B
   [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
}
@end
```

now i put B in the interface builder and wait for it to load via story board
but!

now comes my question :

in all languages i've used to write code, the implementations i've written above would result in the following

1. create B, call its initWithCoder method, see that it needs to go to super, goes to initWithCoder of A, see that it needs to call initialize in A (notice that initialize is an invented method, and its private, it is not declared in the h file of neither class), executes initialize that is written in A
2. returns self, back to initWithCoder of B sees that it needs to execute initialize of B, executes initialize of B, returns B back to whomever wanted to create it with the coder

now i've run this through debug and this is the actual result:
 create B, initWithCoderB -> initWithCoderA ->initializeB ->return B

**my actual question is :WHY did it skip initializeA ?**

Log output

```
2014-05-19 14:45:23.270 MyApp[17780:60b] B initWithCoder
2014-05-19 14:45:23.270 MyApp[17780:60b] A initWithCoder
2014-05-19 14:45:23.272 MyApp[17780:60b] B initialize
2014-05-19 14:45:23.278 MyApp[17780:60b] B initialize
```

If i rename initializeA to initStuffA this is the log output

```
2014-05-19 14:48:41.700 MyApp[17795:60b] B initWithCoder
2014-05-19 14:48:41.701 MyApp[17795:60b] A initWithCoder
2014-05-19 14:48:41.701 MyApp[17795:60b] A initialize
2014-05-19 14:48:41.702 MyApp[17795:60b] B initialize
```

so why can't i have 2 methods with the same name as private, without them overriding eachother?
because they are private, i cannot call super on them

Comment: Rather than two pointless, empty, skeleton classes that could have been explained and some complicated nonsense that would've been better as example code, why can't you just show us the exact code that's producing unexpected results?

Comment: Are you sure initializeB is not being called twice rather than once ?

Comment: but that is my exact problem, that "initializeA" is skipped

Comment: Also show us exactly how you're determining what methods are being called.  If the methods are actually empty, it's not impossible that they got optimized out.

Comment: they are not empty, my initializeA has code to register for keyboard notifications

Comment: @giorashc you are correct, indeed initializeB is called twice, but why ?

Comment: If he is correct, why does his presumption disagree with the description of the actual results in the question?

Comment: Some research done with breakpoints or NSLog statements to see the EXACT execution path can go a really, really long way in questions like this when it comes to methods presumably being not called.

Comment: You can't have two methods with the same name in the superclass and in the subclass without them overriding each other (as @giorashc explained in his answer). It does not matter if they are private or not, because the lookup is done at runtime. - If you don't want that then you have to choose different names. A possible alternative solution are *static* methods, as in [Benefits when using static init in Objective C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23537032/benefits-when-using-static-init-in-objective-c).

Comment: You're overriding the methods, and overriding means use your implementation rather than the base class implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you override the initialize method in class B and you are creating an instance of class B when the initialize method is called it will point to the deepest implementation in the inheritance hierarchy (which in your case is the initialize method of class B)

Comment: This is probably part of why Apple recommends against using property accessors in `init` methods.  You should probably just avoid calling anything on `self` within `init` methods altogether.  The code for setting up the keyboard should be directly within the `init` method rather than in a secondary method probably.

Comment: but i want this code to happen regardless of how you initialize this object, and so i want a new method that does the initialization without having to copy paste it 3 times ?

Comment: does initialize behavior is different for class B and class A ?

Comment: purpose of initialize A to register for keyboard notifications, purpose of initialize B is to change the appearance of B, initializeA is supposed to run because i want to use inheritance

Answer (score 2):

What exactly do you want to achieve here?

If you want an instance of interface B to go through the `initWithCoder` of interface A, then you have no need to overwrite it in interface B. Simply make `initialize` a public method and call:

`- (void)initialize
{
    [super initialize];
    //Any further initialization here
}`

Currently, interface B has no idea that it's super class also implements a method called `initialize` as it is a private method.

If your `initWithCoder:` method in interface A calls your `initialize` method and it is a public method, then when you create an instance of interface B, it will go through the `initWithCoder:` of interface A, then through to the `initialize` of interface B which should then have a call to `[super initialize];` to ensure any code in interface A's `initialize` method is executed.

EDIT 1:

Ok, so interface B inherits from interface A.

By default (ie, with a blank implementation), an instance of interface B will act exactly the same as interface A as all methods will default through to their implementation in interface A.

Interface B, being a child of interface A, has the opportunity to override any methods or properties made **publicly** available by interface A.

To make them publicly available, declare them in the `.h` file.

If you had a method, eg `updateView` in interface A's `.h` file, interface B's implementation then has the opportunity to override it. If you wanted interface B to perform the actions in both itself and interface A, you would need to call up the inheritance tree using the `super` keyword. For example, having something like the following in the implementation of interface B (the child):

`- (void)updateView
{
    [super updateView]; //This calls any code written in interface A's updateView method
    //Add your own code here
}`

This shows your subclass performing inheritance as it gains access to the `updateView` method created by interface A.

Interface B, as it is a child of interface A, will fill in any empty methods with the implementation from its parent class. In your example, you implemented `initWithCoder:` in both interfaces. This is unnecessary, and causes overwriting complications. By leaving out the declaration of `initWithCoder:` in interface B, it will use the implementation of it from interface A, its parent class, which calls to `initialize`. You simply have to remember to call to super every time you override a method implementation and wish to perform both your own code and that of the parent class.

Hopefully this clears up some of your confusions about inheritance within Objective-C.

Comment: i want to use the concept of inheritance

Comment: Check my edit for more information on how this is using inheritance already

Comment: initialize is NOT publically available in any of the interfaces, this is why i thought it would execute each one separately, because theoretically one should not know about the existance of the other

Comment: Why do you need to have them operate separately? You can always just not call to the super implementation from within the child's `initialize` method. This means the method will still get called at the right time, but the parent's implementation will not be executed. But if you want different things to happen, I honestly think you'd be best with different methods, like `initializeX` and `initializeY` in the different interfaces, to make the differentiation between the implementations more obvious.

Comment: If you define a method in a parent class, then call it in the child class without a call to super, the parent's implementation should never be executed as the compiler will see it as an override that doesn't want to call to super.

Comment: i cannot call to super, it is a private method in both classes

Comment: Then simply don't call both the methods `initialize`. Call the one in interface A `registerForNotifications` and the one in interface B `updateAppearance`. That way, when you call `super initWithCoder:`, `registerForNotifications` will be called, then you can explicitly call `updateAppearance` from interface B.

Comment: that defeats the purpose of encapsulation and inheritance, which mean i can never have same method names in both classes , in private state, without thinking why they dont run. thanks anyway

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54029/discussion-between-matthew-hallatt-and-lena-bru).